# How can I show the revision date of a remote git repository's master branch, without cloning the whole repository?

Tags: git, bash, github

I need to know the date and time of the latest revision of the master branch on a remote repository. I've got git installed locally, and I know the HTTPS clone URL for the git repo, which is hosted on GitHub. I know that if I had the repo cloned, I could do `git show --format="%ci %cr" master | head -n 1`, but I need a command that will run quickly, and not leave any sizeable data behind; Cloning a 200 MB repo won't work.

**How can I show the revision date of a remote GitHub repository's master branch, without cloning the whole repository?**

Comment: Using `git` itself I'm not sure you can.  The documentation for the "smart" http protocol is [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Transfer-Protocols#The-Smart-Protocol).  If the repository is hosted on GitHub you could probably use their REST API to discover this information, and that's going to be true for other similar services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do this strictly with Git (i.e. in a way that would work with *all* Git remotes). But there is a solution using [GitHub's `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/branches/:branch` endpoint](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#get-branch), e.g.

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/github/git-lfs/branches/master
# {
#   "name": "master",
#   "commit": {
#     "sha": "df4be34fff5d9c70f5d8b897bbe23fa809776b6a",
#     "commit": {
#       "author": {
#         "name": "risk danger olson",
#         "email": "technoweenie@gmail.com",
#         "date": "2015-08-04T21:24:00Z"
#       },
#       "committer": {
#         "name": "risk danger olson",
#         "email": "technoweenie@gmail.com",
#         "date": "2015-08-04T21:24:00Z"
#       },
#       ...
```

Use your favourite JSON library to extract the `commit/commit/author/date` and / or `commit/commit/committer/date` nodes from the response. The command-line tool [`jq`](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) might be helpful:

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/github/git-lfs/branches/master \
    | jq .commit.commit.author.date,.commit.commit.committer.date
# "2015-08-04T21:24:00Z"
# "2015-08-04T21:24:00Z"
```

For private repositories you'll have to [authenticate](https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication).

Comment: Very creative answer - this one had me stumped! +1

Comment: This works for the written quesiton, but I have one more piece I'd like: any way to do this with read-only access on the github repo? I can split this piece out into another question, since I think this question and answer is probably useful to other people as-is. But if you can answer this piece easily, I think it'd be handy to be part of the same question.

Comment: @E.T., I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. The example I used above to get the date of the latest commit from `github/git-lfs` was done with read-only access; I'm not a committer on that project. Could you clarify?

Comment: @Chris If I do `curl https://api.github.com/repos/CompanyName/RepoName/branches/master` I get `{"message": "Not Found", "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3"}` because it's a private repo. I know I can add `?access_token=[TOKEN]` for a token I set up, but so far it looks like I need to give that token full read/write access to the repo. Is it possible to do this with a read-only token? I don't actually see that level of permission, when I'm editing the token on GitHub.

Comment: @E.T., ah, now it makes sense. I'm not sure if that's possible. As you suggested, asking in a separate question is probably the best way forward.